# $\sum _{j=0}^{\infty }\binom{-p-1}{j} \bigl( -\frac {x} {1+x}\bigr) ^{j}=?$

Tags: summation, power-series

I did try to use geometric series somehow. I have no idea how to evaluate in terms of $p$ and $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generalized binomial theorem
states that
$(1+z)^a
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{a}{n} z^n
$.

Therefore
$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{-p-1}{n} (\frac{-x}{1+x})^n
=(1-\frac{x}{1+x})^{-p-1}
=(\frac{1}{1+x})^{-p-1}
=(1+x)^{p+1}
$.

I am not worrying about convergence.

Comment: i know, it was something easy. thanks!

Comment: @Henning: Yep. I fixed my error. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is the unfolding by the generalized binomial theorem of
$$ \Bigl(1-\frac{x}{1+x}\Bigr)^{-p-1} = (1+x)^{p+1}$$